# Add action to GameObject

Tags: unity, algorithm

So I'm creating a Unity project that has a bunch of buttons (like hundreds) that each do a different thing when pressed.  This is a 3D project and these buttons are also 3D.  I already know how to detect if the player has pressed a button, so I just need to know how to attach an action to one of these buttons.

Should I create a script for each?  From what I've found, it's very memory-expensive and will definitely drop FPS especially for hundreds of buttons.

Should I try to use a UnityEvent?  I don't know if this helps for what I'm doing...?

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify what these 3D buttons are (I guess random 3D objects and on a click you do a trace along the pointer to see which object is hit) and how your actions differ (I guess it's just a grid of buttons and you care about the location in that grid), because it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your actions as public functions in a script, let's call it MyActions.cs, and define you functions like this :

```
  public void myActionForButtonA()
  {
      Debug.Log("Clicked on button A");
  }

  public void myActionForButtonB()
  {
      Debug.Log("Clicked on button B");
  }
```

Then to add a function to a button you have basically two options :

### Add it from code

You can add a listener to a button from the code like this :

```
 private Button myButton;

  void Start()
  {
      myButton = GetComponent<Button>();
      myButton.onClick.AddListener(() => myAction());
  }

  void myAction()
  {
      Debug.Log("This is a custom action.");
  }
```

### Add it from the inspector

Select your *Button* object in the hierarchy, open the *Button component* of your object and then in the *On Click ()* section, select your script (MyActions.cs) and the right function to perform (myActionForButtonA for the button A as you guess).

[image]

Comment: Ehh... but one problem.  This isn't a Canvas button.  It's a 3D cube that's triggered inside the code.

Comment: So basically when the player's raycast points at a button and clicks, it triggers.  The thing is that the code is very general and only returns the name and tag of the collider (the button).

Comment: I don't wanna just do `if (button1 is pressed) { do task #1 }` 500 times because that would be way too long and hard to see...

Comment: That can be handled by changing it to one function that takes an int parameter, and then each button has a different number assigned.

Comment: Hmmm... @jhocking that's interesting.

Comment: @jhocking just to be clear, that means I create a different function inside the same class and call it by that number?

Comment: basically instead of myActionForButtonA(), it would be declared as myAction(int number)

Comment: If your actions are very similar it would work, otherwise it's exactly the same as doing "if (button1 is pressed) { do task #1 }" since you have to manually tell it what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try to make a base class and make new class inheriting from the base when you want a button to do something different:

For example, a base class like this:

```
public abstract class BtnHandler
{
    public abstract void OnClicked();
}
```

Then you make a new class to handle button A action:

```
public class BtnAHandler : BtnHandler
{
    public override void OnClicked()
    {
        // do the what this button supposes to do
    }
}
```

Assign the BtnAHandler class to your button A in the scene. 
In you clicking detection method, you will have:

```
void ClickedOnButton(3DButton btn)
{
    btn.GetComponent<BtnHandler>().OnClicked();
}
```

This is a very simple setup. You could go a little complicated by adding different parameters, different state of clicking, etc.

Generally speaking, using some inheritance ideas in your codes will make it easier to maintain and easy to scale.

Thanks!

Comment: Does not help for the implied issue; that the asker will have problems if they have to create a script for each action, as you suggest.

Comment: The problem he/she mentioned "From what I've found, it's very memory-expensive and will definitely drop FPS especially for hundreds of buttons."does not seem like a real problem. "So I'm creating a Unity project that has a bunch of buttons (like hundreds) that each do a different thing when pressed. " - I think the behaviours of the buttons are all defined, if it is defined, it is ok to put the behaviours into scripts. Creating class for each of the defined action should be fine.